# Accessing classes from maven project to another java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on maven project cloned from github "https://github.com/tomp2p/TomP2P" after importing it in eclipse juno and completing all the required environmental setup now i want to use classes and methods into my own java project but it giving me error.

[My project tespeer with tompeer cloned from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJxXD.png)

pom.xl for testpeer-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>testpeer</groupId>
<artifactId>testpeer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.3</source>
<target>1.2</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<dependency>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>net.tomp2p</groupId>
<artifactId>tomp2p-parent</artifactId>
<version>5.0-Beta9-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>





</project>
```

pom.xml for tompeer

Comment: What does the build path for your project look like?

Comment: Did you modify TomP2P code? If not, you should probably include it in your Maven project by following the [instructions on TomP2P website](http://tomp2p.net/dev/).

Comment: In Projects section it has Tompeer. @Chris

Comment: No, i havent modified any file from that project(Tomp2p)...But it gives me error at  import net.tomp2p.futures.FutureDHT @Valentin

Comment: @Sonal Please edit your question to include your pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project pom.xml file needs to be changed to something like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>testpeer</groupId>
    <artifactId>testpeer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>tomp2p.net</id>
            <url>http://tomp2p.net/dev/mvn/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.tomp2p</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomp2p-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.0-Beta8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: It worked....Thanku so much @Valentin u jst made my day